# URL changes when try to request it

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

Good evening, everyone! I study cheerio and faced with a problem. I try to make a http request. Here's the code:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

export function getWeb(link){
    console.log(link);
    var request = require("request"),
    cheerio = require("cheerio"),
    url = link;

    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            console.log($);
        } else {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        }
    });
}
```

When I try to launch it, I get the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz2tE.jpg)

The problem is that I pass one URL (http://rasp.guap.ru/?g=null), but request "uses" another (https://rasp.guap.ru:80/?g=null). How to fix this?

Comment: The call to `request` is fine. Make sure that the `link` parameter receives, in fact, the `http` url. Also, it is a bad practice to use `require` inside functions. You should write them at the start of your file.

Comment: @JuanScolari, this is exactly http, I used `console.log(link)`, to see what I receive (first line on the screenshot). About `requiere` got it, thanks. Can be else smth wrong?

Comment: It is working fine in my environment https://repl.it/@hoangdv_0959/RipeStupidEnvironments